# Sum first values of non-unique data in different category

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a table consisting of 3 types of costs and each type of these costs has several cost IDs, as below:

| Cost ID | Amount | Cost Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IT01 | 100 | Direct cost |
| IT03 | 300 | Indirect cost |
| IT04 | 400 | Indirect cost |
| IT02 | 200 | Direct cost |
| IT05 | 500 | Overhead |
| IT01 | 100 | Direct cost |
| IT05 | 500 | Overhead |
| IT03 | 300 | Indirect cost |
| IT04 | 400 | Indirect cost |
| IT03 | 300 | Indirect cost |
| IT02 | 200 | Direct cost |
| IT05 | 500 | Overhead |
| IT01 | 100 | Direct cost |

I want to have a summary of each of these cost types and for each of them, only the 1st value of each cost ID is added in. For example,

|  | COST SUMMARY TABLE |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Direct cost: | 300 [=IT01 + IT02] | [Only add up the 1st value of each cost ID of the same type] |
| Indirect cost: | 700 [=IT03 + IT04] | [Only add up the 1st value of each cost ID of the same type] |
| Overhead: | 500 [=IT05] | [Only add up the 1st value of each cost ID of the same type] |

What formula do I use?

I have insert the link below for the file that may be easy to explain.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/8vzpab0qbmxryey/Excel+query.xlsx/file

Comment: Will ***all*** of the ```IT01```s and ***all*** of the ```IT02```s ***always*** be Direct costs?

Answer (score 0):

*You need one Helper column which determines Unique & Duplicate IDS to get the desire results:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell D2:

  `=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)>1,"D","U")`

*Where D is duplicate & U is Unique.*

- Formula in cell I3:

  `=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$14=$H3)*($D$2:$D$14="U")*($B$2:$B$14))`

**N.B.**

- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*
- *You may hide the Helper Column.*